# Paging in a select tag without the next and prev page types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, data-paging

I'm trying to create a select tag paging with the following code:

```
<select ng-change="params.page(page)" ng-model="page" ng-options="page.number as page.number for page in pages"></select>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

Further debugging by using the following code:

```
<select ng-change="params.page(page)" ng-model="page" ng-options="page.number as page.number group by page.type for page in pages"></select>
```

brings me to the conclusion that the previous and the next pages (located at pages.type) are also included in the pages array.

[image]

So my question is, how do can I fix this? Is there a way to create an alternative array of only the pages that are really only pages or a way to filter the pages array based on the given types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to filter the "prev" and "next" page objects out of the pages array by defining a filter. I did this by adding | myFilter  to the queryand adding a filter to my app.